# Can Kafka split records for you?

Tags: split, apache-kafka

Does Kafka provide any facilities for operating on messages that are published to its topics? I have a need to publish a large number of messages to my Kafka broker, but would prefer to bundle them all together as a batch, and then (if possible) let Kafka split them out into individual (smaller) records/messages for me...and *then* publish them to a topic.

Basically, what I **currently** have:

1. Producer takes a large amount of information and splits it into individual records
2. Individual records are published to Kafka topic
3. Consumer consumes individual records off of Kafka

And what I want as **desired** behavior is:

1. Producer takes a large blob of text and sends it to Kafka topic
2. Kafka (somehow) is configured/programmed with splitting logic that splits this blob into individual records
3. Consumer consumes individual records off of Kafka

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: You can't do anything like that

Comment: @smeeb:  There is something native to Kafka: Take a look at the recently introduced Kafka Streams library ([docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#streams), and [way more docs](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/)).  For example, a good starting point would be the `flatMap()` function in the [Kafka Streams DSL](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#kafka-streams-dsl).

Comment: Thanks @miguno (+1) - I will take a look at that. However, in glancing at the docs, I can't tell where these stream processors are actually running: are they running on the Kafka server (somehow, as plugins), or do they live inside the consumer? Or somewhere else? Thanks again!

Comment: Kafka Streams is a Java library.  So a "Kafka Streams application" is a plain old Java application.  And you'd run such applications on client machines at the perimeter of a Kafka cluster.  That is, they are not running on the Kafka server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such facility exists natively, but you can do it easily enough with something like Apache Camel, which is a full-blown routing library and is built exactly for this sort of task. Here, you would consume from one topic that contained the bulk records, do the splitting and republish onto another topic with the split records. Using the Java DSL, the code would look something like this:

```
from("kafka:brokerHost:9092?topic=records-bulk&groupId=testing&autoOffsetReset=earliest&consumersCount=1")
    .split(body(String.class).tokenize("\n"))
    .to("kafka:brokerHost:9092?topic=records-individual");
```

The example above uses the [camel-kafka](https://camel.apache.org/kafka.html) component and treats each line as an individual record, but there are many other ways to choose from for [splitting a payload](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html). The easiest way to get started with Camel is via a [Spring Boot project](http://start.spring.io/) that includes Apache Camel - this will allow you to build a standalone executable that you can place anywhere relative to your brokers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Jakub (+1) - I was just about to update my question that I've used Camel in the past for exactly this, but wanted to first see if there was anything native to Kafka. In ActiveMQ, for instance, you can do similar things from directly inside the web UI. I'll keep this question open for another day or so to see if anyone else has any other ideas, but am leaning heavily towards your recommended approach - thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb:  As I said in my comment to your question above, yes, there is something native to Kafka: the new Kafka Streams library of Apache Kafka (see my comment above for links).

Comment: While I think it's important for others to be aware of Kafka Streams, its important to note that this is a client-side library (I assume there are both producer and consumer patterns available through it?) and *not* something actually running on the Kafka server.